# Java script that reads a excel file and displays that data on a html webpage when the page is opened

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I need a little help. I'm creating a webpage that will automatically read an excel document in a folder when the webpage is opened and then display the data in a table on the webpage. I have tried several different java scripts but cant seem to figure it out. I don't want to load the information into a database table on the server. The data in the excel document will be the work week, engineer on-call, contact information and manager on-call for that week. We have several different teams and each team will have their own webpage. The excel sheet will be updated often so i need for the script to just locate the file and load automatically when the page is loaded. I have seen several examples on this site but none of them work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depending the format of the excel file. Easy if csv, but more complicated with the xml as you have to dig into the tags to get usefull information ( according the information is'nt formula ).

Comment: The files will be saved in a folder in the csv format. The managers will have access to this folder so if updates to the schedule are needed to be made they can easily make them. i was looking for a script that will point to the folder location and then pull the information from the file when the page is loaded. Sorry i should have added more detail the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Nicolas, founder of Appizy (http://appizy.com) a online software that convert Excel file to dynamic webpages (HTML, CSS, Javascript).

If I get your issue correctly, your managers could use Appizy to create HTML report from Excel file and then put the file on the webserver. Then you can include the html file to your actual webpage with a bit of PHP:

```
    $content = file_get_contents('example.html');
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Best
Nicolas

Answer (score -1):

The determining factor here is: where are the files coming from?

The traditional way to handle an output of data is to have the data on the server the website is served from. Whether on the filesystem or in a database as you mentioned. If it's on the server, it's typically easier to parse it when the request is made to load the page, using something like php. Then output the HTML. The other option is to have the Excel file in a public folder, so it can be requested from the browser. Make an xhr request for text/plain, and parse the data you get back.

You might have to do some fiddling with the mime type if you are using a true excel file, over CSV. I strongly recommend having the files saved as CSV, so you're not having to deal with a proprietary format.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned you agmcleod in the reply i gave to @guillaumePelletier. But the files will be in the CSV format on the same server where the website files are. we are all the IT team just different parts (windows, Unix, Mainframe, network, ect..) so the managers have access to the servers to update the schedules and on-call list.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? i need the java script and need to see how to place the code in the html page so it will show. Any help on this is be greatly appreciated.